# How does LinkedHashMap internally preserves the insertion order of objects

Tags: java

LinkedHashMap delegates all the calls to its parent HashMap. it also supports access-ordering and insertion-ordering based on value of accessOrder.
if accessOrder : true then access order is used
else accessOrder :false insertion order is used

public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)

but how is access-ordering and insertion-ordering of the objects internally supported by LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap is Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

[The source code for the OpenJDK 6 version of `LinkedHashMap` is available here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java) Basically, the implementation keeps a doubly-linked list of all of the entries, and the entries' order is simply their place in the list.